# Scale not display in google visualization chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I need to add label and scales for both axes bars. But they are not visible as in the image. Sometimes chart does not render (not drawing, usually first request).

This is the code I'm using:

```
var data=new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string','Date');
    data.addColumn('number','Distance');
    var finalData=[];

    for(i=0; i<distanceValues.length;i++){
        var keyPair=[(data[i]['Date']),parseInt(data[i]['Distance'])];
        finalData.push(keyPair);
    }

    data.addRows(finalData);

    var options={
            chart:{
                title:'Distance',
                subtitle:'KM'
            },
            legend: {position: 'none'},
            sortAscending: true,
            sortColumn: 0,
            width: 600,
            height:200,
             axes: {
                  y: {
                    Distance: {label: 'Distance (KM)'}
                  }
             }
    };


    var chart=new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById("testChart"));
    chart.draw(data,options);
```

[image]

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: @WhiteHat I have added google.load in main script and I did not add any waiting before drawing the chart  There isn't any possibility to hidden the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `legend: {position: 'none'}` which requests Google Charts to hide the labels. Remove it or change as below depending on the position where you want to place your legend.

```
legend: {position: 'right'} //top, right, bottom or left
```

To change scale type (if that's what you are asking), use

```
vAxis: {
        scaleType: 'linear' // linear,log etc
  }
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/_pirateX/ewp1kgm9/) or code snippet below -

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
          'packages': ['corechart']
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Date', 'Distance'],
              ['Service', 168],
              ['NAME 1', 42],
              ['NAME 2', 36],
              ['NAME 3', 35],
              ['NAME 4', 34],
              ['NAME 5', 30],
              ['NAME 6', 24],
              ['NAME 7', 21],
              ['NAME 8', 18]
          ]);
          var options = {
              legend: {
                  position: 'right'
              },
              chartArea: {
                  right: 150,
              },
              vAxis: {
                  scaleType: 'linear'
              },
          };
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart6_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart6_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in your example scales for both sides are not displaying. Is there any way to make it happen?